# T-SQL join table only when the table is not empty

Tags: t-sql, join, sql-server-2012

I have the following tables with one column (RecordID):

```
TableOne
101
102
103
104
105
106

TableTwo
101
102
103
104
```

and want to make join between them only when TableTwo is not empty. This could be done with sample IF statement, but in my real situation this would lead to a lot of code duplication.

I have try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM
TableOne T1
WHERE exists (select 1 from TableTwo where T1.RecordID=RecordID)
      and exists (select 1 from TableTwo)
```

using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027482/t-sql-using-cross-apply-with-delete-statement) , but the same logic is not working for me - it works only when the second table is not empty, if it is empty, nothing is return.

Has anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: could you provide estimated resultset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you want to select all if there's no row in `TableTwo`. You need an `OR` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT 
   T1.* 
FROM
   TableOne T1
WHERE 
   EXISTS(SELECT 1 from TableTwo WHERE T1.RecordID=RecordID)
   OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableTwo)
```

[**SQL-Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ef80/1/0)