# SQL issue: JOIN on empty table

Tags: sql, inner-join

For example we have the following SQL query

```
select T1.name
from table1 T1
join table2 T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
```

I have made join table2 only if it is NOT empty. If table2 is empty I don't make join

```
select T1.name
from table1 T1
```

Can I solve it by one SQL query?
It would be good to use only SQL standard.

Comment: left join or inner join? you have both tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195117/t-sql-join-table-only-when-the-table-is-not-empty

Comment: you need to use `left outer join`. Try `select T1.name from table1 T1
left outer join table2 T2 ON T1.id = T2.id;`

Comment: I have to use inner join.
Oasis is right. This is duplicate question.
To resolve it I use `EXISTS` and `OR NOT EXISTS`